# Why Phalanger PhpNetClassLibrary failed to load

Tags: php, iis-7, phalanger

I installed Phalanger not in standard program files but in another directory.

When executing sample code installed automatically by phalanger, it failed with error message :

```
Library assembly 'PhpNetClassLibrary, Version=3.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=4af37afe3cde05fb' ... specified user doesn't have valid profile
```

(I'm translating error message from foreign language not sure the exact english)

Update : I tried this http://www.php-compiler.net/?p=354
but I can see PhpNetCore.dll but no PhpNetCore.IL.dll in my phalanger dir.

Comment: PhpNetCore.IL.dll was removed from Phalanger recently. Not needed.

Answer (score 1):

> The specified user does not have a valid profile

is a .NET exception. If you are running IIS application, try to change the Application Pool identity to NetworkService.